# rdlc localReport.SetParameters() taken 7 seconds

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have a local report in rdlc. It takes about 7 seconds for localReport.SetParameters() to process. The rdlc is a big engineering report with many formulas and data. Is it possible problem for the report to take long time to initially process?

Comment: The time is a function of the size of the database, the speed of the SQL Server Machine, the amount of memory, and the amount of data that is being returned.  As the database size grows so will the response time.  It is impossible to tell what the maximum response time will be.

Comment: thanks, jdweng. Since it is an engineering report in rdlc and to reduce the rendering and processing time within rdlc  all engineering calculations and data were completed prior to loading the rdlc file from an assembly (dll). Therefore, there are four (4) datasets from Objects of the engineering calculations. Each dataset has around 80 properties for the engineering report formulas and data fillings. No any calculations or dynamic expressions within the rdlc. However, even that, the initializing rdlc report takes too long time around 7 seconds. But, localreport.Render() takes about 2 seconds.

Comment: RDLC is html format and can be opened with Notepad. there is usually one of more CommandText sections which are queries into the database and depending on the size of the database will depend on the response time.  You can run the command text as queries inside SQL Server Management Studio to see how long each query takes.  The html queries can have special characters like an ampersand and may need some minor edits before running in SSMS.